# Agora Unable to Start Cloud Recording

Tags: api, live-streaming, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

```
        options1 = {
            'method': 'POST',
            'url': 'https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/' + appID + '/cloud_recording/resourceid/' + resourceId + '/mode/2/start',
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic XXX'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "cname": "lol",
                "uid": "1",
                "clientRequest": {
                  "token": token,
                  "recordingConfig": {
                    "maxIdleTime": 30,
                    "streamTypes": 2,
                    "channelType": 0,
                    "videoStreamType": 0,
                    "transcodingConfig": {
                      "height": 640,
                      "width": 360,
                      "bitrate": 500,
                      "fps": 15,
                      "mixedVideoLayout": 1,
                      "backgroundColor": "#FF0000"
                    },
                    "subscribeVideoUids": [
                      "123",
                      "456"
                    ],
                    "subscribeAudioUids": [
                      "“123”",
                      "“456”"
                    ],
                    "subscribeUidGroup": 0
                  },
                  "recordingFileConfig": {
                    "avFileType": [
                      "hls"
                    ]
                  },
                  "storageConfig": {
                    "accessKey": config.writeAccessKeyId,
                    "region": 3,
                    "bucket": config.bucket,
                    "secretKey": config.writeSecretAccessKey,
                    "vendor": 1,
                    "fileNamePrefix": [
                      "directory1",
                      "directory2"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              })

        };

        request(options1, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            console.log(response.statusCode);
```

I referred to the Agora's Cloud Recording API. Authentication and resourceId work fine. The response.statusCode is always 404. Unable to locate the error. I tested on Postman and the URL is not working as well. May I know if any attributes are entered wrongly? Does the user have to join the channel before the recording can start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your url, you have specified mode/2/start. 
It should be mode/mix/start.

You can refer the documentation here for more information: 
https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=All%20Platforms#parameters-1

Comment: May I know if the recorded video starts saving on start or on stop?

Comment: It should start saving on start.

Comment: I have ensured that the uid for acquire and start is different from the users' in the channel. Do I need to take care of anything else like the transcodingConfig?

Comment: transcodingConfig is optional.

Comment: Is it possible to start multiple recording with different channel names but the same uid?

Comment: Yes. It is possible

Answer (score 0):

Does cloud recording work for Android and iOS as well?

Comment: is it mandatory to generate a token to start cloud recording, also I'm using AWS s3 service for cloud storage so my vendor would be 1 but I'm located in India Mumbai so there's confusion about the region in agora docs could anyone help me with that.

Comment: it is mandatory. the region will be the s3 region, not the region you are in.

Comment: I'm getting a response from query api as                                                                             {"resourceId":"resourceId Value","sid":"sidvaule","serverResponse":{"status":6,"fileList":"","fileListMode":"string","sliceStartTime":0}}.  but the video filename is not present im not getting whats worng response

Comment: u might want to check the token u passed in when starting a recording

Comment: i generating the token from node js and then passing it start api and gets this  {"resourceId":"resourceId Value","sid":"sidvaule","serverResponse":{"status":6,"fileList":"","fileListMode":"string","sliceStartTime":0}}. but there are some case where i get response as this  {
    "resourceId": "rid",
    "sid": "sid",
    "code": 404
}.  could you help me to solve this issue

Comment: Based on the error code 404, it seems that your URL is wrong. I would suggest printing out all the values to check them visually. Please refer to https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/restfulapi/#/Cloud%20Recording/start too.

Comment: "subscribeVideoUids": [
                      "123",
                      "456"
                    ],
                    "subscribeAudioUids": [
                      "“123”",
                      "“456”"
                    ],  how do i get these subscribeAudioUID and subscribeVideoUID from

Comment: My files are getting stored in s3 but when i play it online theres no audio and video in it. can you help me with that issue